# how to update multiple records upto some limit using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb and nodejs in my appilication. I have 2000 records, which is assigned to me. Now i want to assign 1000 records to another user. for that I am using map function that was not a good idea, So Can you please help me to update the records without using map function. I am attaching my query below.

```
[err, data] = await to(
  Leads.find({ assignedTo: payload.assignedUser, company: companyId })
    .populate("createdBy", ["_id", "fullName"])
    .populate("assignedTo", ["_id", "fullName"])
    .sort({ createdAt: 1 })
    .limit(payload.limit)
);

data.forEach(async (element) => {
  element.assignedTo = payload.assignedToUser;
  await to(element.save());
});
```

**Records**

```
  {
    _id: "617a84bf01c98424e00daf52",
    callLogId: null,
    result: null,
    assignedTo: "615be641d38b3c47dccbd63f",

    extraFormObject: null,
    subResult: null,
    apptDate: null,
    nextcallDate: "2021-10-28T11:02:50.516Z",
    callDate: null,
    leadId: "617a84b401c98424e00d1310",

    company: "6155c2758609663d10fff796",
    createdAt: "2021-10-28T11:08:50.962Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-10-29T11:02:12.407Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "617a84bf01c98424e00daf53",
    callLogId: null,
    result: null,
    assignedTo: "615be641d38b3c47dccbd63f",

    extraFormObject: null,
    subResult: null,
    apptDate: null,
    nextcallDate: "2021-10-28T11:02:50.516Z",
    callDate: null,
    leadId: "617a84b401c98424e00d1311",

    company: "6155c2758609663d10fff796",
    createdAt: "2021-10-28T11:08:50.963Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-10-29T11:02:12.408Z",
  },
```

Help me out from this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using updateMany? are you using Mongoose?

Comment: thank you @v1shva for responding. if i use updateMany it was changing all the records. is there any way to updateMany with limit option

Comment: yeah i am using mongoose.